# What's the most combinations i can have in a matrix?

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine a chess board. I am in the midle of the board, and i can make a max of 23 jumps in a row. Houses that i was in can't be reviseted and i can only jump to the surrounding houses.

How much combinations of jumps can i do?

Example, if i have the board:

```
AB
CD
```

If i'm in position A, and i can make 3 jumps, i could have the combinations ABC, ABD, ACB, ACD, ADC, ADB

I am tring to apply this to a very big matrix with a max of 23 jumps, so the limits of the board exceed the chess ones. Imagine a matrix 100x100 and you where in the midle spot for example. This is not a homework, i just put in the tag because i don't know what other one to put.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't imagine a middle spot on a 100 by 100 board

Comment: Your moves are like a king in chess, and you actually allow 22 moves as you are counting the starting position.  You are asking for non-reentrant king's paths.  If the board is large the sides don't get in the way at all, so (for a starting square near the middle) the number of paths will be constant.

Comment: @Platonix:  any square close enough to the middle works the same.  As long as it is 22 cells from any side, you are fine.

Comment: Ah, point taken

Comment: I get $1,8,56,368$ for $1,2,3,4$ jumps (using your definition).  This finds only http://oeis.org/A081626 in OEIS, which is not your sequence

Comment: @RossMillikan yeap, and i want to know that max value is. I have a programing issue, and i want to see if it's better to have all the combinations or find another algorithm basicly.

Comment: An upper bound is $8 \cdot 7^{21}\approx 4.468\cdot 10^{18}$  The true value will be smaller than this, as this assumes you have seven choices for each move, but I would be surprised if it were smaller by even a factor $1000$.  You would have a hard time calculating or storing all these.

Comment: Jesus crist... That's a lot lol I need to find another way. Thanks Ross :)

Answer (score 1):

We can approximate the number experimentally.  The number of [self-avoiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk) king walks (on an infinite board) of length $22$ on is $$p \times 8^{22}$$ where $p$ is the probability of a random king walk of length $22$ being non-self-intersecting.

I ran 50 experiments where I generated $10^9$ random king walks and estimated $p$ to be:

```
0.00334704, 0.00334645, 0.00334825, 0.00334736, 0.0033472, 0.00334607, 0.00334735, 0.0033473, 0.00334746, 0.0033479, 0.00334619, 0.00334661, 0.0033482, 0.00334675, 0.00334656, 0.0033471, 0.00334864, 0.00334583, 0.00334701, 0.00334788, 0.00334651, 0.00334665, 0.00334801, 0.00334719, 0.00334678, 0.00334696, 0.00334761, 0.00334668, 0.00334712, 0.00334794, 0.00334602, 0.00334742, 0.00334782, 0.0033466, 0.00334661, 0.00334756, 0.00334833, 0.00334606, 0.00334655, 0.00334799, 0.00334669, 0.00334717, 0.00334739, 0.00334693, 0.00334706, 0.00334727, 0.00334731, 0.00334707, 0.00334642, 0.00334806
```

By the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), this should follow an approximate Gaussian distribution, and the above data is used to estimate the mean and standard deviation.

This data has sample mean $\mu \approx 0.003347$ and sample standard deviation $s \approx 0.00000066$.  So, $p$ has a high probability ($>99\%$) of being within $(\mu-3s,\mu+3s)$.  So the number of walks has a high probability of being within $$(2.468 \times 10^{17},2.471 \times 10^{17}).$$